# `cout<<nullptr` giving error though `nullptr` has type `nullptr_t` from C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, void-pointers, nullptr

**Code-1**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Error: Use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'nullptr_t')
```

Even there is specific type for `nullptr` why it is showing error.
But

**Code-2**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << (void*)nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
0
```

Works fine. Why it work with `void*` even it is not a type ?

Comment: `void* even it is not a type` `void*` is a type. It's the type `void*`.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you need to do a C-style cast (like `(void*) nullptr`) you're probably doing something wrong. It's better to do a `reinterpret_cast` instead, and best is no cast at all (if possible).

Comment: I see your quoted 'error' as an IntelliSense message (sometimes) in Visual Studio 2019 but I get no compiler error or warning using MSVC or clang-cl. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @AdrianMole `basic_ostream& operator<<( std::nullptr_t )` is introduced in C++17. It was an ambiguity in earlier versions.

Comment: @AdrianMole `jetbrains CLion`  `C++17,20,23`  . Yes for `C++17` on `codechef` it is not giving error ? but I think `CLion` is advance compiler

Comment: CLion is not a compiler.

Comment: yeah sorry. `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++`  this is show in `Clion C++compiler setting` I know this is path. I didn't downloaded compiler `Clion` downloaded it directly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for recommendation. I didn't even know till now such casting present in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::cout << nullptr;` works in C++17. If it doesn't work for you, then either you're not using C++17 or your language implementation's support for C++17 is incomplete.

Prior to C++17, `std::cout << nullptr;` didn't work because the overload `std::ostream::operator<<(std::nullptr_t)` didn't exist and there were no unambiguously best overload that `nullptr` could be implicitly converted to.

> Why it work with void* even it is not a type ?

`void*` is a type and it works becase the overload `std::ostream::operator<<(const void*);` exists.

Comment: @AbhishekMane Any IDE is good if you like it. I'm disappointed by the lack of a free community version myself, but if they get enough paying customers without it, then I suppose people do like it.

Comment: looks like this is implemented in libstdc++ starting from GCC 9